# JSONPickle Issues Python

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have a few models that I deserialize to store in Redis using JSONPickle. I am having an issue where some of my enums are sporadically serializing. I get the following when I print the data stored in Redis. This is what is coming out of the jsonpickle serialization process:

Working:

```
"Error": {
    "py/reduce": [
        {
            "py/type": "Enums.InputError"
        },
        {
            "py/tuple": [
                -1
            ]
        },
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

Not Working:

```
"Error": "<InputError.NONE: -1>",
```

Is there a way to force jsonpickle to always serialize or something simliar? It looks like it's sometimes serializing to a string.

Serialization Code:

```
# value is a custom object
jsonpickle.encode(value, make_refs=False)
```

Deserialization Code:

```
# value is a jsonpickle encoded string (output from the serialization above)
jsonpickle.decode(value)
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you could also show us the serialization and deserialization code

Comment: @JamesRusso Done!